# Derivatives and Average Velocity

Tags: calculus

So I am struggling to understand the methodology (which I am sure is just as important as getting the answer).  I saw a similar question but did not find the responses to be helpful.  I need more clarity.

If a ball is thrown straight up into the air with an initial velocity of 85ft/s the height in feet after t second is given by y=85t-16t^2.

I am trying to find the average velocity (spoiler I know it is 69). But I can't understand the process of getting there using the from 1 to .1; 1 to .01 and 1 to .001 and then seeing where the numbers lead. I don't know the formula needed to fill in the other questions. The teacher of my class only shows how to do this with a graphing calculator and I don't have one to work with right now and would prefer to understand how to do one without it.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! Just for the users who would be interested: the similar question you are referring to is [this one](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/499074).

Comment: @Vic Are you sure you're looking for the average velocity? Average velocity should be zero, since the upward and downward halves of the trip mirror each other. Maybe you're looking for average position, or max height? But none of these has 69 as an answer, I think.  Is it the average over the entire trip of the ball?

Comment: you are correct; i definitely need to be more attentive to the verbiage.  I know that 69 is correct for the instantaneous velocity at t=1. I have a pic of the problem I am working on but it wont let me post...or rather I don't know how to post.  I think the goal is to show how i reached 69 as the instantaneous velocity at t=1 by showing the velocity at numbers infinitesimally close to 1.  But i cant seem to get that formula correct to show my work.

Comment: The instantaneous velocity at time $t = 1$ is $53$, not $69$. Generally, the instantaneous velocity at time $t$ is $85 - 32\cdot t$ (until the ball hits the ground or some other object), which is the derivative of the height with respect to the time. $69\frac{\text{ft}}{\text{s}}$ is the average velocity of the first second of the travel. Generally, the average velocity between times $t_1$ and $t_2$ is $\frac{p_2 - p_1}{t_2 - t_1}$, where $p_k$ is the position at time $t_k$. After one second, the position is $85\cdot 1 - 16\cdot 1^2$ feet up in the air, and at time $0$ the height was $0$.

Comment: you must disagree with my calculus professor; we have unlimited time to attempt the hmwk online and it tells us when something is correct.  I have 69 correct...I just don't know how to fill in how I got there (probably because it was a bit of a guess).

Answer (score 1):

Since you asked for a process, I'll give you two since I'm putting off doing my homework.

**Convoluted Solution:** So let's set up the problem. We know that the average value of any function can be given by $$\int_a^b \frac{y(b)-y(a)}{b-a} dt$$

We put our starting time at $0$, since that is when we begin looking at when the ball is thrown.

We know that we'll stop caring about the ball when it hits the ground, which means it's position is $0$, since we have the position function, we simply have to to set it to $0$ in order to find when it hits the ground. In other words, we have to solve $$85t -16t^2 = 0$$

From there, we have to find the velocity function, which is the derivative of the position function. In other words, $$\frac{dy}{dt} = \frac{d}{dt}[85t - 16t^2]$$

I'll let you solve these on your own, but here's the set up integral without the solution $$\int_0^b\frac{\frac{dy}{dt}(b)-\frac{dy}{dt}(0)}{b-0}dt$$

**Easy Solution:** Take a look at [this picture of the position](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e6R1S.png)

From here it should be easy to figure out the average velocity of the ball.

Comment: The problem directly says: If a ball is thrown straight up into the air with an initial velocity of 85ft/s, it height in feet after t seconds is given by y=85t-16t^2. Find the average velocity for the time period beginning when t_1 and lasting  0.1 (blank for answer)  0.01 (blank for answer) 0.001 (blank for answer.  Finally based on the above results, guess what the instantaneous velocity of the ball is when t=1 (blank that I filled in 69 and got correct after trying the formula).  I can't figure what I am doing wrong in the formula when trying to figure for the decimals.